# Доступ к phpMyAdmin по отдельному доменному имени

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos

Команда `rpm -q centos-release` выдает следующее:

```
centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Везде, где я находил мануалы по установке phpMyAdmin, было написано, что доступна она будет по адресу вида `https://ip-server/phpMyAdmin`.

Могу ли я на выделенном сервере установить phpMyAdmin так, что бы был доступ по отдельному адресу типа `https://phpMyAdmin.mysite.ru`?

Comment: нет, **установить** не можете ни по какому **адресу**. вот сделать доступным — да, по любому адресу. с помощью соответствующей настройки вашего http-сервера. // а для желаемого вами использования нового доменного имени начните с настройки dns.

Comment: Можно подробнее здесь или ссылку на другой ресурс?

Comment: [можно, конечно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdns%5D+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Comment: Понял Вас, буду искать в дебрях интернета расшифровку сообщения. Спасибо.

Comment: Предлагаю сформировать комментарий в виде ответа. Он в вполне меня устраивает. Вы ответили на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как вопрос очень «глобален», приведу лишь общий план действий:

1. надо, чтобы обращения к новому доменному имени (`phpmyadmin.mysite.ru`) попадали на ваш сервер. отвечает за это *dns*-сервер, обслуживающий ваш домен (`mysite.ru`).
2. ваш *http*-сервер должен принимать эти обращения (понадобится новая секция *server* в конфигурации программы *nginx*, *virtualhost* — в конфигурации *apache*, и т.д. и т.п.)
3. в этой же секции надо настроить работу «обыкновенного сайта на *php*», корень сайта должен указывать на каталог, в который вы установили/распаковали *phpmyadmin*.
4. опционально: наверно, имеет смысл убрать (или отключить) из конфигурации *http*-сервера то, благодаря чему *phpmyadmin* доступен по адресу `mysite.ru/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Спасибо, с DNS я понимаю. С остальным буду разбираться.

Comment: условно говоря, вам надо сделать «ещё один php-сайт». код для него готов — в каталоге с *phpmyadmin* ([посмотрите — там и `index.php` имеется, всё как положено](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin)), остаётся настроить обращение к этому коду.